# Waves silver plug-in bundel for sound design?

Tags: design, waves, plug-ins

Im going with the waves silver bundel on saturday because it is only $418 right now at sweetwater.com here is the bundel http://www.waves.com/content.aspx?id=8675 
Any reasons why not to get it? I already know I like the L1ultramaximizer and renissance plugins in the bundel but has anyone used the other plugins in the bundel? How are they for your sound design projects?

Answer (score 4):

Only reason not to get is if you want one of the larger bundles. Sweetwater has some sort of arrangement with Waves...the plug-ins/bundles are almost always well below list through them.

You can do some interesting things with Enigma and MondoMod, mainly weird things (but sometimes that's what you want, right?). SuperTap can be useful. MaxxBass is awesome...good for adding some upper harmonics to low end sounds. Can really make them sound more alive and stand out.

Answer (score 3):

I have everything Waves makes.  I use MaxxBass constantly.  I also use Doubler a lot, and find Enigma and the Stereo Imager useful at times.  Q10 is a versatile EQ.  IR1 is a decent convolution verb, if you get some good impulses somewhere.  As you said, the Ren stuff is great and have been go-to plugs for me for years.  It looks like a good starter bundle for the price.

Answer (score 2):

I am fan of Waves and use them daily. Great plug-ing!! I will quote @Shaun Farley

> Only reason not to get is if you want one of the larger bundles.

Answer (score 0):

How does the sound design package compare to the lower priced ones? Are they worth the extra?

Sorry I'm not trying to hi-jack the thread.

Comment: In my opinion the Sound Design bundle is now the best deal Waves has.  If it had been around a year ago, I probably wouldn't have bought the Mercury bundle.  80% of the stuff I use on a regular basis is in the Sound Design bundle.

Comment: @Chuck Thanks for the heads up I plan to buy it in the near future so nice to see it's the best bet :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a collection of the plugins that made Waves famous.
Rbass and Doppler would be nice to add for sound design..

Comment: What's Rbass do?

Comment: @ragamesound Its basically MaxxBass in a different skin, but I personally feel it has a smoother and richer bottom end than MaxxBass does.